# Ionic 7 preflight request doesn't pass access control check (all origin allowed, methods and headers are allowed)

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cors

Code;

```
this.http.post(this.endpoint + "api/auth/signin", {"username": handle, "password": password}).subscribe(r => {
        // @ts-ignore
        if (r["status"] === "authorized") {
          localStorage.setItem("status", "signed_in")
          // @ts-ignore
          localStorage.setItem("token", r["token"])
        }
      })
```

Errors;

```
signin:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'apiurl' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
signin:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'apiurl' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Server has these headers just for testing;

```php
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

And the funny thing is when I add xmlrequest function to the console it works but not on angular version of ionic framework. I am going nuts. Please help...

Comment: The _preflight_ request is made using the `OPTIONS` request method, and your server needs to respond to that with the CORS headers and status code 200 OK. Is that actually happening in your system?

Comment: No, according to the error message that was half hidden behind a scroll bar, it is not: _"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."_

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Since I was paranoid about security I was blocking every request :)